# Move QGIS3 bookmark panel to be in the menu bar without creating a plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is it possible to move the Bookmarks from a panel to be in the top menu bar - so you would get ...Edit--View--Bookmarks--Layer...

and clicking on Bookmarks have a dropdown that has Sydney, Melbourne etc as the point to zoom to?

I understand that we can create a plugin for this but is there a simple customization change that can be done to achieve this?

In Interface Customization all I see it Widgets--QgsBookmarksBase--buttonBox and nothing to make this a menu item.

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge. QGIS almost has this functionality if you access the spatial bookmarks through the QGIS3+ searchbar in lower left if you type b and a space.

[image]